# Javascript/Html/Css Random background-image & Word from two javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, css

Welcome to the forums!
Today I wanted to code a bit in language Javascript/html/css/php but I stuck in a problem.
(I have searched for this problem everywhere,but no results.)

My problem is => I have two array in my js file. The first store the pictures from the directory,and the second one is store the words that I want to select randomly by Math() number #indexes
You can read everything in my codes. I have commented them.

```js
window.onload = chooseGame;

var cGamePic = new Array("football.jpg","baseball.jpg");
var cGameName = new Array("football","baseball");
function chooseGame;
 var rnd_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * cGamePic.length);
 document.getElementById("comp1Game").src = cGamePic(rnd_num);
    document.getElementById("??").?? = cGameName(rnd_num);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Random pics</title>
  <script src="rnd.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container1">
   <h1>Some text 1</h1>
   <!--The next line will be displayed,but not randomly.
   And I want it to the left-side of screen,as background image.
   Like: the text "Some text 1" will be displayed in the random selected image.
   (The some text 1 is selected randomly too,as "football")
   -->
    <img src="res/images/football.jpg" id="comp1Game" alt="Compare1">
  </div>
 
  <div id="container2">
   <h1>Some text 2</h1>
   <!-- The future container to see the 2nd selected image & word in it (right side of screen)
   Like,if js select number 6,the word and image will be "baseball" and "baseball.jpg"
   Shortly,I want to do it.
   -->
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier with jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Random pics</title>
        <script src="rnd.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script> 
    var cGamePic = new Array("football.jpg","baseball.jpg");

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        chooseGame();
    });

    function chooseGame(){
        var pic = cGamePic[Math.floor(Math.random()*cGamePic.length)];
        var name = pic.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

        $("#comp1Game").attr("src",pic);
        $("#container1 h1").html(name);
    }
</script> 

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container1">
            <h1>Some text 1</h1>
            <img src="res/images/football.jpg" id="comp1Game" alt="Compare1">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So,what it does? I don't really understand that "var name = pic.replace" line. The rnd.js is still the same,and I need it? Anyways,thank you! :)

Comment: With "var name = pic.replace" you can extract basename from the path, so the cGameName array is unnecessary.  And no need to use rnd.js. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just make it simple

If the array [GameName] and [GamePicture] values are in same index, then just following the below snippets

```
var cGamePic = new Array("football.jpg","baseball.jpg");
var cGameName = new Array("football","baseball");
var randomItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * cGamePic.length);
var comp1GameTitle = document.querySelector("#container1 h1");//Heading from main container
var comp1GameImage = document.querySelector("#container1 img");//Image from main container
comp1GameTitle.innerHTML = cGameName[randomItem]; //Random Title
comp1GameImage.src=cGamePic[randomItem]; //Random image
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jh5tkfpp/)

Comment: It should work even if you change your CGameName array values different from your CGamePic , but make sure both array values should place  it in same index.

Comment: No need to use Jquery library, just try with plain javascript

Comment: Can you show an example how to generate *two* background image with this(one in the left-side of screen and one in the right-side of screen. [IMG | IMG]? And if you can show me how to render the *two* text to the images?

Comment: two background image from different array or same array?

Comment: either same or different you just create a another new variable
var anotherVariable = Math.floor(Math.random() * NewArray.length);

Comment: I wanted to select two background image from same(img_array) and two word from same(string_array). <maybe this done with css,but I have no idea> and the code still hanging with one picture(it isn't generate the random pic) :(

Comment: Then the above code should work, let me update my existing code.

Comment: I have added "demo" link, please check it

Comment: I want thank you without words,but at this moment,I can do it only. Really thank you. :)